# Find the projection of the function $cos(\pi t)$ in the subspace $H^{\perp}_{0}\subset L^{2}[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Find the projection of the function $cos(\pi t)$ in the subspace $H^{\perp}_{0}\subset L^{2}[0,1]$ where $H_{0}=\{x(t)\in L^{2}[0,1]:x(t)\equiv 1\}$.

Currently, I'm taking my functional analysis class and this problem was suggested during a lecture. I feel it is a straightforward problem, but I'm still stuck. Here is what I was doing.

> If we want that $cos(\pi t)\in H_{0}$ then $t$ must be a of the form $T=2n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
> On the other hand the orthogonal complement of $H_{0}$ is given by
> $$H^{\perp}_{0}=\{y(t)\in L^{2}[0,1]:\langle x(t), y(t)\rangle\,\,\forall x(t)\in H_{0}\}\\
> =\{y(t)\in L^{2}[0,1]:\int^{1}_{0}x(t)y(t)dt=0\,\,\forall x(t)\in H_{0}\}.$$
> So, we only need to find the functions $y(t)$ that makes the integral zero, but $x(t)=cos(\pi t) =cos(\pi 2n)\equiv 1$, so the following holds,
> $$\int^{1}_{0}cos(\pi 2n)y(t)=0\\
> \text{so,}\,\,\int^{1}_{0}y(t)=0$$

From there, I doubt if what I have done is right. First, I am not sure that what I did with $cos(\pi t)$ is valid. Next following the line of reasoning that I have there the functions that would be orthogonal would be $sen(3n\pi)$, right?

Thank you very much for reading my post, any help would be super helpful, as I feel I'm just complicating myself too much or I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in your reasoning. You don't want $\cos(\pi t)$ to belong to $H_0$, indeed it is not the case. According to your definition, the set $H_0$ only contains the constant function with value $1$. Thus
$$
H_0^\perp = \left\{ x\in L^2[0,1]\; \colon \; \langle x,1\rangle=\int_0^1 x(t)1\; dt = 0 \right\},
$$
that is, $H_0^\perp$ consist of all the functions in $L^2[0,1]$ whose integral is $0$.

Now, note that
$$
\int_0^1\cos(\pi t)\;dt = 0, 
$$
consequently $\cos(\pi t)\in H_0^\perp$, and hence $\cos(\pi t)$ is its own projection onto $H_0^\perp$.